# guild.get_member_named(name) is returning 'NoneType' inspite of existence of such member

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have enabled intents all through my code and developer portal;got necessary permissions for the bot to 'see' the other members but still the method returns NoneType for almost all users(only exception is Dyno)
Now I need a complete check through my program and the permissions and settings
if it doesn't get sorted after the check then the question topic gets adjusted accordingly

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx,args1):
  guild = bot.get_guild(ServerID)
  member = guild.get_member_named(args1) #getting NoneType here
  await ctx.send('member.mention') #Assuming the existence of member coz I know there is such one
  
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: I am very new to discord.py
Please don't mind if this question looks silly and forgive me thinking I am your little student who is yet to learn coding in Discord.py
I am willing to learn more about coding and hence trying to take help from the seniors

Comment: Have you enabled intents ? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: @NathanMarotte Sir yes I have enabled them from discord developer portal

Comment: Give intents all and check, it's work

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the name correctly? Is there any reason you're using `Guild.get_member` instead of using the `MemberConverter`?

Comment: @kacper1236 Sir how to give intent all?
@ŁukaszKwiecińskiSir I used that function because I don't yet know how to use ```MemberConverter```

Comment: Take a look at the commands introduction to learn more about converters: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters

Comment: discord.Intents.all()

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
discord.utils.get(guild.members, name='theusernamehere')  #replace"theusernamehere" with the person username
```

To get by id use this

```
discord.utils.get(guild.members, id='idhere') #replace "idhere" with the person id
```

or you can just use `arg1: discord.Member`